# How to generate key private key from .pem file in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, encryption

How to generate `private key` from `.pem` file in iOS / how to read `.pem` file in iOS?

Comment: please see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: have look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762555/creating-pem-file-for-apns) solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647220/reading-and-writing-rsa-keys-to-a-pem-file-in-c