# Generate RSA public/private key with OpenSSL?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

The main problem is that I'm quite new to C, and the OpenSSL documentation is not clear enough for me, I've tried using [Reading and writing rsa keys to a pem file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647220/reading-and-writing-rsa-keys-to-a-pem-file-in-c), but I don't quite understand it. For example, how does the `create_rsa_key()` function creates both the private and the public? And where does `pCipher` come from? And what's the point of the `pcszPassphrase`?

I'll explain as if it was some sort of pseudocode, this is what I want to do, and the parts in bold are those I don't know how to do it:

- **generate private key and public key as buffers in hex (client)**
- send the public key to the other endpoint safely (client)
- encrypt some data with a random 256 bit password using AES256 CBC (server)
- **encrypt the password using the public key (server)**
- send the encrypted data to the client (server)
- decrypt the encrypted 256 bit password using the private key (client)
- **decrypt the file**

Basically I know how to handle AES encryption/decryption and the communication protocol, they're already implemented anyway, my issue is RSA, and I need hex format not base64 or pem as I'm working with sockets and sending and storing as binary data.

Comment: By the way I tried to be simple, I know there are security leaks in my block example, but there's much more behind what I say here.

Comment: By "hex format" you mean the ASN.1 encoding, right? (of which, all basic PEM really becomes is a header, footer and the base64 encoding of the RSA key ASN). Is that all you're really after?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot http://etherhack.co.uk/asymmetric/docs/rsa_key_breakdown.html

Comment: In that website you can find the structure in hex of what I want... which is in fact, ASN.1

Comment: Regarding the ASN.1 representations of the public and private key, both `i2d_RSAPublicKey` and `i2d_RSAPrivateKey` should do what you want. And **decrypt the file** followed immediately thereafter by "Basically, I know how to handle AES encryption/decryption" are direct contradictions.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're right however i2d_RSAPublicKey is making my buffer basically a bunch of 00

Comment: That function doesn't use "your buffer". It allocates one. You send it a pointer-to-pointer and it does the allocation, populates the result, and returns the length of the buffer allocated.

Comment: See [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae64a70076436165).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on IRC, the answer to the create_rsa_key question is addressed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589818/37923 - it's not meant to work that way.

pcszPassphrase is meant to be the password/phrase to protect the private key. It would be provided by the user, but isn't a requirement.