# Segmentation fault with generating an RSA and saving in ASN.1/DER?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa

```
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

#define RSA_LEN 2048
#define RSA_FACTOR 65537

int genRSA2048(unsigned char **pub,unsigned int *pub_l,unsigned char **priv,unsigned int *priv_l){

    RSA *pRSA = NULL;
    pRSA = RSA_generate_key(RSA_LEN,RSA_FACTOR,NULL,NULL);

    if (pRSA){
        pub_l = malloc(sizeof(pub_l));
        *pub_l = i2d_RSAPublicKey(pRSA,pub);
        priv_l = malloc(sizeof(priv_l));
        *priv_l = i2d_RSAPrivateKey(pRSA,priv);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned char *pub = NULL;
    unsigned int publ;
    unsigned char *priv = NULL;
    unsigned int privl;
    genRSA2048(&pub,&publ,&priv,&privl);


    RSA *privrsa = NULL;
    d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&privrsa,(const unsigned char **)&priv,privl);

    RSA *pubrsa = NULL;
    d2i_RSAPublicKey(&pubrsa,(const unsigned char **)&pub,publ);

    unsigned char * data ="01234567890123456789012345678912";
    unsigned char encrypted[256];
    unsigned char decrypted[32];

    int len = RSA_private_encrypt(32,data,encrypted,privrsa,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    RSA_public_decrypt(len,encrypted,decrypted,pubrsa,RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
}
```

I've tried to find the bug by checking with gdb but as being fairly new to C I haven't find any clue to tell me what is happening but I believe it's an allocation problem, however according to the d2i_RSAPrivateKey and similar, they're supposed to allocate the space by itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

compiled as `cc foo.c -lcrypto`

This is the follow up of this question:

[Generate RSA public/private key with OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959142/generate-rsa-public-private-key-with-openssl)

As I reference I used @WhozCraig example in the comments, which can be found here, even when it's quite different, it was a lot of help.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae64a70076436165

Comment: I was told the mallocs were the problems by <schquid> and <Xgc> from irc. :)

Comment: It would help a lot if you added comments to explain what you think the code is doing, or what it's supposed to do. Frankly, I find it baffling. What do you think you are allocating enough space for in the two `malloc` lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pub_l = malloc(sizeof(pub_l));` is simply not needed. Nor is `priv_l = malloc(sizeof(priv_l));`. Remove them both from your function.

You should be populating your out-parameters; instead you're throwing out the caller's provided addresses to populate and (a) populating your own, then (b) leaking the memory you just allocated.

The result is the caller's `privl` and `publ` are untouched and thus the decoding back to `RSA` is dysfunctional, as both values are indeterminate.

Comment: You got it again... :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> pRSA = RSA_generate_key(RSA_LEN,RSA_FACTOR,NULL,NULL);
> ```

I think this is wrong. I know you are supposed to use `RSA_generate_key_ex`, and I think it needs a `BIGNUM`, not an integer. You should have gotten a warning. See [`RSA_generate_key(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html) for details.

Your code should look something like:

```c
BIGNUM* exp = BN_new();
ASSERT(exp != NULL);

int rc = BN_set_word(exp, RSA_F4);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
ASSERT(rsa != NULL);

rc = RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 2048, exp, NULL);
ASSERT(rc == 1);
```

Be sure to call `BN_free` on the `BIGNUM`, and `RSA_free` on the `RSA` pointer.

---

> ```
> RSA *privrsa = NULL;
> d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&privrsa,(const unsigned char **)&priv,privl);
>
> RSA *pubrsa = NULL;
> d2i_RSAPublicKey(&pubrsa,(const unsigned char **)&pub,publ);
> ```

For this, it looks like you are trying to separate the public key and private key. For that, use `RSAPublicKey_dup` and `RSAPrivateKey_dup`. See [Separating public and private keys from RSA keypair variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970494/608639).

---

Its not clear to me what you are trying to do with the following. You should state what you are trying to do...

```c
pub_l = malloc(sizeof(pub_l));
*pub_l = i2d_RSAPublicKey(pRSA,pub);
priv_l = malloc(sizeof(priv_l));
*priv_l = i2d_RSAPrivateKey(pRSA,priv);
```

I'm just guessing, but I'm going to say its all wrong. `sizeof(priv_l)` is the size of a pointer, so its 4 or 8 bytes. You're also overwriting the pointer passed in by the caller...

Also see [OpenSSL's rsautl cannot load public key created with PEM_write_RSAPublicKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547646/608639). It talks about saving the keys with *SubjectPublicKeyInfo* and *PrivateKeyInfo* in both ASN.1/DER and PEM formats.

By writing the *{Public|Private}KeyInfo*, the OID gets written to the key. That's important for interop. You also use the `RSA*` (and even an `EVP_PKEY*`), and not byte arrays.

Comment: No warning, the first part is ok even when I know I use old style (deprecated) code; the second answer is to get the ans1 representation so it's ok, and the deadly code was the pointers as mentioned.